# Mongo: Select datasets with variable in third level

Tags: mongodb

In a collection I have multiple datasets like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "YAEYvJ7tvXxTvnFtv",
    "article" : [
        {
            "title" : "Article 1",
            "detail" : [
                {
                    "edition" : "second edition",
                    "year" : 2000,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "BpsCfbhZuoXfEvREG",
    "article" : [
        {
            "title" : "Article 2",
            "detail" : [
                {
                    "edition" : "third edition",
                    "year" : 2010,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "xJD8gRTHMfsBb9TTG",
    "article" : [
        {
            "title" : "Article 3",
            "detail" : [
                {
                    "edition" : "first edition",
                    "year" : 2000,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to filter for those datasets with year = 2000? So in this example I would like to get the dataset for "YAEYvJ7tvXxTvnFtv" and "xJD8gRTHMfsBb9TTG".

```
collection.find({year: 2000});
```

Comment: try this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
db.collection.find({"article.detail.year": 2000});
```

If you want to be more precise, you can spicify array position:

```
db.collection.find({"article[0].detail[0].year": 2000});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to query a nested or embedded document (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-embedded-documents)

Your query should be

```
collection.find({article : {detail : {year : 2000}}});
```